# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property in a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this error is extremely common. I have read on it and seen the other questions posed here, however I simply cannot figure out how to fix my particular problem.

I have a windows form with two comboboxes on it and other controls that are irrelevant to the case at hand. I have set up a method for when the first combobox changes and I want to change the list of items in the second one by some measure.

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
        String Name = cb.Name;
        Name.Replace("Rank", "Target");
        cb = Form1.ControlCollection.Find(Name, false);
        for (int i = cb.SelectedIndex; i < Ranks.Count-1; i++)
        {

        }
    }
```

"Form1.ControlCollection.Find" raises the error in the title. Since I cannot make a new instance of Form1 (as I believe that will not reference my existing winform but make a new one?) and making the ComboBox_Selected... method static does not help at all, I don't know what to do.

I did try

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.ControlCollection.Find(Name, false);
```

and

```
this.ControlCollection.Find(Name, false);
```

but the error did not go away

Comment: Form1 is the name of the class, not the name of an instance of that class. If this code is run inside the class Form1 just change Form1 with _this_

Comment: @Steve, it didn't help. :/

Comment: In which form class the code above runs?  _this_ is a keyword intended to  represent the current instance of the class where the code runs. A better understanding of your context is required. How do you reach this point? How do you create an instance of the class that executes the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged event handler?

Comment: I have also forgot to add that you need to use the syntax _this.Controls.Find_ not _ControlsCollection_

Comment: `this` should have worked. I'm surprised it didn't. Did you get a new error with that code changed?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you probably want to use `Name = Name.Replace("Rank", "Target");`

Comment: Thanks to you all! @Steve, yes, "this.controls.find" might just work, it just says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to Combobox" and I have been trying to figure out how exactly does one convert it for a while.

Comment: @sgmoore, oh, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is part of the class `Form1` then you should use the C# keyword [*this*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) to refer to the current instance of the class.
Your code has also other problems that should be fixed in this way

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    String Name = cb.Name;

    // Strings are immutable so you need to reassign
    // the result of Replace to the same variable....
    Name = Name.Replace("Rank", "Target");

    // Find returns a Control array, you need to add some checking
    // Before using the control instance returned (if found)
    Control[] found = this.Controls.Find(Name, false);
    if(found.Length > 0)
    {
        cb = found[0] as ComboBox;
        if(cb != null)
        {
            for (int i = cb.SelectedIndex; i < Ranks.Count-1; i++)
            {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a gem! I'm sorry to do this, but could you also tell me how to remedy "Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion"?

Comment: @mathgenius That would be a separate question.

Comment: @mason well, you are correct but in this context my original code had an error, so a fix was required

Comment: @Steve It doesn't really matter if it's in your original code or not. The question you asked was not about that, and it's unfair to expand your question. When you ask a question it's not "please fix every issue with my code". That would make it hard to create a reference of helpful Questions and Answers (the goal of Stack Overflow). So try to figure your issue out. If you can't get it, then post a new question and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mason My _answer_ had an error! I cannot leave an answer with a clear error in it. The OP (in not very clear words) noticed _my_ error in the answer and asked help about it. So no I don't think that this qualifies as a request to _fix all the issues with my code_...

Comment: Thank you, Steve, you made me realise I was trying to assign an array to a non-array variable this whole time! This just fixed it for me, blindness, my old nemesis. :D